# Simplify boolean POS expression from 2 terms to 1 term. (Or 10 to 3)

Tags: algebra-precalculus, boolean-algebra

How can the expression AB'CD' + ABC'D' be simplified to AC'?

If context is needed, then this is the full expression:

A’B’C’D’ + A’B’C’D + A’BC’D + A’BCD + AB’C’D’ + AB’C’D + AB’CD’ + ABC’D’ + ABC’D + ABCD

And the simplified answer is:

BD + B'C' + AC'

I've gotten to BD + B'C' but I can't seem to simplify two stray terms down to AC'.

Comment: It can't: suppose $A=C=1, B=D=0$. Then $AB'CD'+ABC'D'=1$, but $AC'=0$.

Comment: You seem to be assuming that if $X+Y=X+Z$ then $Y=Z$. That is not so, in Boolean algebras; no cut law.

Comment: No I'm just trying to simplify down... I was able to simplify everything down to two of the final expressions, but I had 2 terms hanging around that I figured must simplify to the last term in the answer, AC'

Comment: That what I mean. It seems that you started from an expression such as $AB'CD'+ABC'D'+F(A,B,C,D)$ and concluded that $F(A,B,C,D)=BD+B'C'$, and then you though that it would be enough that $AB'CD'+ABC'D'=AC'$, which is correct: that would be sufficient, but not necessary. So your calculations may be correct, but just your strategy didn't work. Try another way...

Answer (score 1):

For the first part $\quad AB'CD' + ABC'D' = AD'\quad$ because both BB' and CC' are represented  by $AD'.\quad$
I believe the entire eqpression simplifies as shown in the Veitch diagram below.

[image]